How can I return "owning iterator" from trait function in Rust?
I have a trait Iterable with a function owned_iter returning "owning iterators" (i.e. iterators that generate values without reference to any external data source). I don't want to name the iterator (it can contain type names of closures etc.), so I used return-type impl Trait.

trait Iterable{
    // 'static is added here to restrict the returned iterators to be "owning iterators"
    fn owned_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=usize> + 'static;
}

// OK example
struct A{}
impl Iterable for A{
    fn owned_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=usize> + 'static {
        (0..10).into_iter()
    }
}

// Error example
struct B<T>{
    x: T,
}
impl <T: Iterable + Clone> Iterable for B<T>{
    fn owned_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=usize> + 'static {
        let y = self.x.clone();
        y.owned_iter()  // error[E0597]: `y` does not live long enough
    }
}

It works for structs like A, where the concrete type of the returned iterator is known. However, in struct B, I'd like to use the output of function owned_iter of another type and return it. This should be possible since I restricted that the return type of owned_iter is 'static, but I get an error saying that the returning iterator might refer to the local variable. Why is it, and how can I work around this problem?
Rust Playground

This smells like it might be a bug. When I desugar the RPIT into an associated type, it compiles successfully.

It is indeed odd. Returning self.x.owned_iter() without cloneing self.x first also compiles.

It looks like 'static is ignored and the same lifetime as &self is added. self.x.owned_iter() thus succeeds, but cloning self.x doesn't.

As further evidence that this is probably a bug, I can stash the iterator in a static variable (if I ensure it's Send), which proves that the lifetime of the iterator is indeed independent of y: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5d14093a36a461912477fa69b1623933


When I desugar the RPIT into an associated type, it compiles successfully.

Desugared version compiled.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=50d603d24982c890d022dc9548731165

Oh, this is an even simpler proof that it should be fine: it also works if you first box the iterator as a trait object... https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b6f8a4a8451eeeffb9ebee802d27f3d6

Created a bug report https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/131490
